# How do I use javascript to search through PDF file titles and/or content.

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

How do I use javascript to search through PDF file titles and/or content. The files are stored in a sub folder called "pdf_files" . once the user searches and a match is found a link will appear and they can click it and it will show them the PDF like normal.

Comment: this question is too broad and requires a large commitment on the answerer to create a solution

Comment: what else would you want to know?

Comment: What have you tried? What system is the backend and frontend running on, what is the setup like? This one question has actually a few pretty big questions surrounding it, besides just "how do I use javascript to search through PDF file titles and/or content". It would be helpful to narrow your question to a specific thing you need help on, and show that you have made a decent attempt on tackling the problem

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), Mozilla's JavaScript solution to read, manipulate PDF files. Please let me know if it helps.